# sql: Sorting date according to soonest date

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a column name closing date in MySQL which stores date in the format 'month-day-year'. I have the following data:

```
2/25/2021
2/26/2021
3/10/2021
3/21/2021 <- Today's date
3/22/2021
3/25/2021
3/29/2021
```

I need to sort it so that the upcoming date should come first:

```
3/21/2021 <- Today's date
3/22/2021
3/25/2021
3/29/2021
2/25/2021
2/26/2021
3/10/2021
```

How can I achieve this? I tried using the order by ascending and descending and did some research but couldn't do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Start with altering the column to proper `date` data type. (With char/varchar, different years will be troublesome. Calculating date differences too.)

Comment: Are you looking for the _current_ date to be at the top of the list?  What about the other dates, how should they be sorted?

Comment: It should be so that the upcoming date should be in ascending order and the past dates should appear at the last of the records preferably in ascending order as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `order by` statements/logic, not just columns.  So, you can use something like:

```
ORDER BY theDate = CURDATE() DESC
```

This should put the current date at the top.  As for the others, you can add a 2nd clause to sort them as you wish:

```
ORDER BY theDate = CURDATE() DESC, theDate DESC
```

---

UPDATE: If you want the *current* date first, with future dates following, and then everything else, you can just add a `> CURDATE()`.

```
ORDER BY theDate = CURDATE() DESC,
    theDate > CURDATE() DESC,
    theDate ASC
```

---

UPDATE 2: This can be simplified using `>= CURDATE()`.  Thanks, [@jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642402/sql-sorting-date-according-to-soonest-date/67642455#comment119561665_67642455).

```
ORDER BY theDate >= CURDATE() DESC, theDate
```

Comment: OP wants today _and future dates_ first, then passed dates.

Comment: @jarlh I see... I think I can fix this :)

Comment: `ORDER BY theDate >= CURDATE() DESC, theDate`

Comment: @jarlh I thought about that, but I wasn't sure if it would put the current date first or not (using `>=`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are showing dates both prior and after, you could add an order by clause to your query such as

```
order by
   abs( datediff( curdate(), theDateColumn ))
```

So, as of Mar 21,  Mar 25 might show as 4 days away, but Mar 20 would show 1 day away.  The absolute() function ignores +/- confusion, so you should be able to get what you need.